# Shared Preferences aren't setting up

Tags: java, android

I am using following code in the start of my activity

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, transferToOrFromArray);
         spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         transferTo.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
         transferFrom.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

         SharedPreferences CNPASettings = getSharedPreferences("CNPA",0);
         transferTo.setSelection(spinnerArrayAdapter.getPosition(CNPASettings.getString("transferTo",spinnerArrayAdapter.getItem(0))));
         transferFrom.setSelection(spinnerArrayAdapter.getPosition(CNPASettings.getString("transferFrom",spinnerArrayAdapter.getItem(0))));
```

When i complete doing stuff, i press Done button which contain following code.

```
                        title = "Success";
                        error = "Transfer has been done";
                        SharedPreferences CNPASettings = getSharedPreferences("CNPA",0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = CNPASettings.edit();  
                        prefEditor.putString("tranferFrom", transferFrom.getSelectedItem().toString());  
                        prefEditor.putString("tranferTo", transferTo.getSelectedItem().toString());  
                        prefEditor.commit();  
finish();
```

But whenver i create the activity again, it passes default values `spinnerArrayAdapter.getItem(0))`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
("tranferFrom", transferFrom.getSelectedItem().toString());  
                        prefEditor.putString("tranferTo"


     CNPASettings.getString("transferTo"
     CNPASettings.getString("transferFrom"
```

tranfer and transfer..... Spelling Mistakes......

Answer (score 0):

for setselection use the position numbers not the strings.According to that position we set the current focus to the spinner.
for Reference check the below link 
[Shared Preferences in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746063/shared-preferences-in-android/4746226#4746226)

Comment: No the problem is CNPASettings.getString("transferTo",spinnerArrayAdapter.getItem(0)) returning spinnerArrayAdapter.getItem(0).. When it should return the value , i saved in it.