# Views with same ids getting the same attrs when restored

Tags: android

I have a custom component with one RadioGroup that has two RadioButton, ids `@+id/radioButton1` and `@+id/radioButton2`. On the other hand, there is a TabActivity with five tabs. On each tab, this component is used more than one time.

Here's the problem, when orientation changes and the activity is recreated, all of the RadioButton is loaded with the same attrs, this includes `android:text`, `android:margin` and even the styled attrs that i've created. It also happens with all the CheckBox that has the same ids.

I spent some time trying to discover why this was happening and concluded that android is doing that in onRestoreInstanceState. If I comment the line that calls the super method it works fine.

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

}
```

Is this how it's supposed to be? Or what could one do to cause this?

I'm guessing that it's not a normal behaviour because when a custom view is created, it inflates the same layout with the same views that has the same ids. So it's not possible to instantiate a new custom view generating different ids for its child every time. Using the code above or `android:configChanges` on the manifest seems to be a bad workaround to me. So, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've experienced this too. In fact, I've spent a couple of days trying to track this bug down. The worst part is, in my case, these views receive a bad value and that immediately triggers a change in the state of the thing represented by the View, which means I'm corrupting the state.

I'm seeing this behavior in a SeekBar that's embedded in a custom view that groups a SeekBar with some other components. I reuse my custom view in various places in the Activity, and of course being able to reuse the XML file is preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some time searching for an explanation, I finally found a great one from Romain Guy in the android google group, although it doesn't mention custom views.

"It's ok to use same ids except when you need the views to save their state. The id is 
what identifies views when their state is saved so the toolkit simply 
think that your two views are the same. But that's true within an 
activity only. "

"There is no problem using the same id in two different activities. And 
there is no problem using the same id inside the same activity if 
you're careful about what you're doing (for instance, if the views 
with the shared ids do not need to save any state.) In your case, 
because the activities are part of a set of tabs, they are actually 
tied to a unique context which means you will run into problems with 
shared ids. "

[Here's the link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=&hl=pt-BR#!searchin/android-developers/views%2420same%2420ids%2420on%2420restore/android-developers/qcclW4oekVY/7pVg8Ti1RwgJ).

Comment: Rather than just linking to an external resource, you should include a (small) relevant part of it here - a link by itself can rot and isn't a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

What does your savedInstanceState method look like?

I would suggest that the variables assigned to the radiobutton texts are not persisting between orientation changes. Remember, the activity is completely rebuild/restarted when orientation changes.

Comment: I don't override onSaveInstanceState method. I only override onRestoreInstanceState to prevent android reloading views with same ids with the same AttributeSet.

Comment: The radiobuttons texts are receiving values of the last occurrence of my custom view, it's like android is sweeping the whole layout associating a view state with its id(In the savedInstanceState bundle, I guess) and then loading this state for all views that has the id it was associated.

Comment: Have you tried creating an alternate landscape layout file by creating a layout-land folder and copying the same layout xml files into it? Android automatically switches between the two depending on the device orientation. This might force the device to rebuild the view with "new" information.

Comment: An additional thought: What is the state that your app goes through that requires persistence? It might be worth while having that object stored separately as a variable, string or array within Shared Preferences. The app could then rebuild the labels of the radio buttons based on the stored variable rather than trying to store all the labels between operations.
[Here is some code examples of using Shared Preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746063/shared-preferences-in-android)

Comment: My app has a large form that the user need to complete. This form is tied to an object that has more that seventy fields, so it requires persistence to prevent the user losing data when android have configuration changes.

Comment: I don't need to save the labels of the radio buttons because they are static. The problem is that android is doing it itself and the only way I can prevent that to happen is to do some workarounds that ain't pretty, at least I think that.

Comment: Is there a reason why the form needs to work in landscape AND portrait mode?