# using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

in the case my topic is a duplicate please link the corresponding topic, but I didnt find exactly what I'm looking for.

In my app I have a prefs.xml file which contains a list prefeference named "list" with the values "default theme" and "other theme". Those values can be selected by the user in a PreferenceActivity. In some other activity, I have to check WHICH value was selected and call one of two methods (setUpDefaultTheme or setUpOtherTheme) which I've created already. That check must be made just after the activity starts so the user sees one of those two themes, depending on the option the was selected in Preferences.

I know that I have to use SheredPreferences to do so, but I cant manage to get it working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
[shared preferences in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746063/shared-preferences-in-android)

or this
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=shared+preferences